# jQuery error in a theme

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm trying to run a jquery script for my Drupal 8 site, but in the error console, I get a `TypeError: $ is not a function`. I know this usually happens when jQuery isn't loaded, but the `jquery.min.js` is loaded fine. Is it loaded too late? Do I perhaps need a wrapper?

In my theme.libraries.yml, I have the following:

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

My script is simply

```
$('#some-element').on('click', function() {
  // Do something
}
```

I would think this is all I need, or am I overlooking something?

Edit:

I don't think this is a duplicate question since:

1. This is Drupal 8
2. The dependency is defined in the libraries file. I would think this would take care of exactly the problem described in the other question.

Comment: I found the solution, but I would like to provide an answer, since it differs from the Drupal 7 behaviour.

Comment: `since it differs from the Drupal 7 behaviour` should be the same as D7.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but it isn't.

Comment: I wouldn't second guess @Clive.

Comment: I'm not second-guessing him, I've provided the explanation why this isn't a duplicate question, and I'm telling YOU, it's not the same as Drupal 7.

Comment: There's no answer to "Why am I getting $ is undefined" that's specific to any version of Drupal. It's simply jquery running in no conflict mode, which means there's no global `$` variable. That's covered in the dupe, there isn't anything specific to Drupal 8 to help answer your question @pim. There may be some related extra stuff, but you asked about something very specific, which was introduced in Drupal 7 and hasn't changed since

Comment: Drupal 8 needs Drupal as a dependency as well. The documentation isn't very clear so i thought it might be useful to answer that question for other people. Thank you however, since your link led me to the solution.

Comment: That's true, but that's the sort of tangential info I'm talking about. You haven't mentioned the `Drupal` variable at any point and it doesn't have any bearing on the question you actually asked, which is how people will end up here via search engines. If the question was "why is `Drupal` undefined", then that extra info becomes very useful. Otherwise, it's just s distraction from the actual question: why is `$` undefined?"

Comment: Glad you got it sorted either way

Comment: Let's not get into nit-picking - fine with me if you want to consider this question as a dupe, but in my opinion it isn't. Simply looking at the D7 question or the related docs doesn't help solve the problem. I checked the D8 docs beforehand, and I couldn't find this directly. Btw, by leaving out the Drupal dependency, you still get $ is undefined, not Drupal is undefined. Anyways, it's up to you, but I would consider it useful for people getting into Drupal 8. Thanks either way!

Comment: I wasn't trying to nitpick, if missing that dependency produces the same error as missing jquery then I stand corrected :) Re-opened, please fo ahead and put the answer in if you still want to

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I will. And thanks for checking all these questions, it must be a hell of a job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal 8 jQuery is added in the non intrusive way, this means that `$` is not defined in the global space.

What you should do is to use closures (this is a very good idea, as it makes it easy for you to fix potential issues with colliding variables names. `$` is used by other frameworks as well.

This is done by wrapping your code in a anonymous function so you don't need to get variables from the window object but can get them from the function definition. This means that you can easily change the source one place and it will effect all of the script you have written.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  // It's best practice to use strict mode, can help avoid some browser issues.
  'use strict';

  // Generally you always want to use behaviors, remember to depend on Drupal js.
  Drupal.behaviors.name = {
    // Called on document ready and when no elements is added to the page.
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(".selector", context)...
    }
  }

  // Sometimes you just want to do something when DOM is ready.
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
  });

})(window.jQuery, window.Drupal);
```